# $http returns promise instead data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I started with AngularJS yesterday, so I'm sure I'm being extremely dumb on this question, but here we go.

This is my service.

```
angular.module('UserService', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('User', ['$resource', '$http', function($resource, $http){

    User = {};
    User.login = function (){
        var url = 'http://example.com/api/user/login';
        loginInfo = $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: "user=user&pass=imagethereisahugepasshere",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(data){
            loginInfo = data;
        })
        return loginInfo;
    }


    return User;


}])
```

If I attach it to my controller and call `console.log(User.login())`, it returns me the promise instead the response (which is right, according to network Chrome tab).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Go through [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's an asynchronous request, it will not have completed when the function returns. That's why you have a success callback to do whatever needs to be done when the request actually completes.

Getting a promise back allows you to handle it in a different way - you can use .then() to do something after the promise is completed. But it's important to know that the function will return before it gets data back.

Comment: OK. What do you suggest, then? I guess I need to think another way, but I don't know how.

Comment: The simple answer is just do what you need to do in the success callback, or use the promise: loginInfo.then(function(data) {//dostuffhere});. It is important to have it in your mind that your code won't always flow straight through - functions will be invoked as data is returned. So you should bear that in mind when you structure the code. Angulars data binding helps a lot because it takes care of a lot for you.

Comment: I did it, and it worked. Now I must think on some way to integrate it on the flow that's in my head. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:-

```
 return--> loginInfo =$http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: "user=user&pass=imagethereisahugepasshere",
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function(data){
                loginInfo = data;<-- doesn't come into picture
            })
    return loginInfo;<--$http service promise rather than local data variable
```

Obviously loginInfo is a $http service promise .